# String to NSdate not working

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert the string 3/12/15 to NSdate. And i am using the below code. But after converting, the date becomes 2015-03-11 18:00:00 +0000. But i want the same format just like it is now in string. Any kind of help would be very appreciative.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: dateStr];
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is done in your local time zone, while simply printing a date it will be printed in GMT (hence "`… +0000`")

```
NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:date]);
```

This will print the date in local time zone

Comment: I checked it now and thats exactly what i wanted. Thanks